# Create language locales in D8

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am attempting to create/enable the UI to allow users to create translations in D8, and I need to create locales (e.g. `en-us`, `en-gb`, `en-ca` for English, `es-mx`, `es-es` for Spanish, etc). I've gone through the directions I've been able to find, and I am not seeing where to add specific locales after adding the base languages (at `admin/config/regional/language`). Or in the `Translate` tab on content items. Where do I go to enable specific locales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use locales separately, each has to be added as a custom language.

1. `/admin/config/regional/language/add`
2. Choose **Custom language**.
3. Enter the locale that you want as the **Language code**.
4. Enter the **Language name**.